# count of objects (0) differs from count of keys (1)

Tags: objective-c, object, key, plist, nsdictionary

An error keeps popping up that says theres a different count of keys then objects, and the program keeps crashing.

the code below is what is called into question.

```
-(void)saveData //error is in here
{

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
//get documents path
NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
//get the path to our Data/plist file
NSString *plistPath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Data.plist"];

//set the variables to the values in the text fields
self.topScores = highScore.text;

//create dictionary with values in UITextFields
NSDictionary *plistDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects: [NSArray arrayWithObjects: topScores, nil] forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"bestScore", nil]];

NSString *error = nil;
//create NSData from dictionary
NSData *plistData = [NSPropertyListSerialization dataFromPropertyList: plistDict format: NSPropertyListXMLFormat_v1_0 errorDescription: &error];

//check if plist data exists
if (plistData)
{
    //write plistData to our Data.plist file
    [plistData writeToFile:plistPath atomically:YES];
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"Error in saveData: %@", error);
    [error release];
 }
}
```

The code works, but then it crashes at about here

```
         if (newTopScore > [topScores intValue]) 
        {
            topScores = ([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", newTopScore]); 
        }

        highScore.alpha = 1; 

    [self saveData];
```

Comment: the error reads -[NSDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:]: count of objects (0) differs from count of keys (1)'

Comment: It means your plist is corrupt. Probably has an array element in there somewhere.

Comment: would you mind specifying what you mean by an array element because I don't really see any as far as I can tell

Comment: Which line in particular is the error arising from?  If you can't figure it out from the stack trace you can step through to see where it fails.

Comment: the error is the one I listed above, but for some reason the code crashes here  
                if (newTopScore > [topScores intValue])
            {
                topScores = ([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", newTopScore]);
            }

Comment: i think that the code means that if the int newTopScore > the int value of the string TopScores, then make topscore equal to the string value of newtopscore
tell me if im wrong.

Answer (score 2):

It must be this line:

```
NSDictionary *plistDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects: [NSArray arrayWithObjects: topScores, nil] forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"bestScore", nil]];
```

And it must be that `topScores` is nil, meaning that the objects array is of size 0 while the keys array is of size 1.

You need to find out why `topScores` is nil.

For example, try running this code:

```
NSDictionary *plistDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:@[] 
                                                      forKeys:@[@"bestScore"]];
```

You will get:

> `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:]: count of objects (0) differs from count of keys (1)'`

Comment: The reference reckons an `NSIllegalArgumentException` would be raised in that case: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSDictionary/dictionaryWithObjects:forKeys:

Comment: @trojanfoe Yes, that's right (although actually a `NSInvalidArgumentException`). That's where the OP's error comes from. See my edit.